# Local addresses not resolved when TP-Link router used

Tags: tp-link, ip-address

Upgraded from DSL to Cable internet.  Previously a 2Wire modem/router was used.  Now a Netgear CM500 is the modem and a TP-Link Archer A7 is the router.  Machines on the LAN cannot see one another. File sharing does not work.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: A couple versions:   16.04, 16.10 and 20.04

Comment: OK 20.04 is a supported version. You need to be aware 16.10 is EOL and not supported here. 16.04 is only supported till April 22 as it is about to go EOL. Those 2 systems need to be upgraded.

Comment: To everyone who only deals with currently supported versions of Ubuntu - be aware the problem being reported (and addressed) here was observed in Ubuntu 16.04 as well as Ubuntu 20.04. For reasons not related to this issue, no upgrade of older versions is currently planned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu systems must have the packages winbind and libnss-winbind and a modification to /etc/nsswitch.conf. The hosts line in /etc/nsswitch.conf needs wins between files and mdns4,it should read:

hosts:          files wins mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns

A 2WIRE model/router might be assigning local addresses in a different range (192.168.1.nnn) while the TP-LINK router may be assigning addresses in the range (192.168.0.nnn).  Check firewall settings on all the systems of the LAN.

The Ubuntu packages winbind and libnss-winbind are needed for conections associated with Windows systems.

Ubuntu systems on the LAN never were able to resolve local addresses of any other systems so, the local addresses are now hard coded in the /etc/hosts file on each Ubuntu system.  The Windows systems are able to resolve local names - this difference I do not have an explaination for.